# How to concatenate tensors with shape (None,) to another tensors with shape (None, None) (both having the same batch size)?

Tags: tensorflow

I have multiple tensors like this:

```
[value]
[value]
...
[value] (batch_size=n, shape=(None))
```

and multiple tensors like this:

```
[value, value]
[value, value]
...
[value, value] (batch_size=n, shape=(None, None))
```

How to concatenate them to something like this?

```
[value, value, ..., value]
[value, value, ..., value]
...
[value, value, ..., value] (batch_size=n)
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate values? If so, use `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat`

Comment: I solved it by `tf.expand_dims` first because `tf.concat` requires tensors' ranks to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by `tf.expand_dims` tensors with rank 1 first because `tf.concat` requires tensors' ranks to be the same.